# Can not select secure screen lock option on Samsung Galaxy s8+

Tags: security, lock-screens, screen, pattern-lock

I am trying to set my screen lock to pattern/pin/password but it reverts back to a non-secure option (swipe/none).

I have tried:

- Clearing cache
- Clearing credentials
- Removing Nova-launcher

I'm all out of ideas.